# "operator symbol not allowed for generic subprogram" from Ada

Tags: operator-overloading, ada

I want to make subprogram for adding array's elements with Ada.
subprogram "Add_Data" have 3 parameters-
first parameter = generic type array (array of INTEGER or array of REAL)
second parameter = INTEGER (size of array)
third parameter = generic type sum (array of INTEGER -> sum will be INTEGER, array of REAL -> sum will be REAL)

I programmed it from ideone.com. 
(I want to see just result by array of INTEGER. After that, I will test by array of REAL)

```
With Ada.Text_IO; Use Ada.Text_IO;  
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO; Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure test is
   generic 
      type T is private;
      type Tarr is array (INTEGER range <>) of T;
      --function "+" (A,B : T) return T;
      --function "+" (A, B : T) return T is
      --begin
      --   return (A+B);
      --end "+";
   procedure Add_Data(X : in Tarr; Y : in INTEGER; Z : in out T);

   procedure Add_Data(X : in Tarr; Y : in INTEGER; Z : in out T) is
      temp : T;
      count : INTEGER;
   begin
      count := 1;
      loop
         temp :=temp+  X(count);    //<-This is problem.
         count := count + 1;
         if count > Y then
            exit;
         end if;
      end loop;
      Z:=temp;
   end Add_Data;

   type intArray is array (INTEGER range <>) of INTEGER;
   intArr : intArray := (1=>2, 2=>10, 3=>20, 4=>30, 5=>8);
   sum : INTEGER;
   procedure intAdd is new Add_Data(Tarr=>intArray, T=>INTEGER);

begin
   sum := 0;
   intAdd(intArr, 5, sum);
   put (sum);
end test;
```

when I don't overload operator "+", It makes error.
"There is no applicable operator "+" for private type "T" defined."
What can I do for this?

Answer (score 7):

If a generic’s formal type is `private`, then nothing in the generic can assume anything about the type except that it can be assigned (`:=`) and that it can be compared for equality (`=`) and inequality (`/=`). In particular, no other operators (e.g. `+`) are available in the generic unless you provide them.

The way to do that is

```
generic 
   type T is private;
   with function "+" (L, R : T) return T is <>;
```

This tells the compiler that (a) there is a function `"+"` which takes two `T`’s and returns a `T`; and (b) if the actual `T` has an operator `"+"` which matches that profile, to allow it as the default.

So, you could say

```
procedure intAdd is new Add_Data (T => Integer, ...
```

or, if you didn’t feel like using the default,

```
procedure intAdd is new Add_Data (T => Integer, "+" => "+", ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to not knowing how to declare a generic formal subprogram (Wright has shown how to do this for functions), your code has a number of other issues that, if addressed, might help you move from someone who thinks in another language and translates it into Ada into someone who actually uses Ada. Presuming that you want to become such a person, I will point some of these out.

You declare your array types using `Integer range <>`. It's more common in Ada to use `Positive range <>`, because people usually refer to positions starting from 1: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ...

Generics are used for code reuse, and in real life, such code is often used by people other than the original author. It is good practice not to make unstated assumptions about the values clients will pass to your operations. You assume that, for Y > 0, `for all I in 1 .. Y => I in X'range` and for Y < 1, `1 in X'range`. While this is true for the values you use, it's unlikely to be true for all uses of the  procedure. For example, when an array is used as a sequence, as it is here, the indices are immaterial, so it's more natural to write your array aggreate as `(2, 10, 20, 30, 8)`. If I do that, Intarr'First = Integer'First and Intarr'Last = Integer'First + 4, both of which are negative. Attempting to index this with 1 will raise Constraint_Error.

Y is declared as Integer, which means that zero and negative values are acceptable. What does it mean to pass -12 to Y? Ada's subtypes help here; if you declare Y as Positive, trying to pass non-positive values to it will fail.

Z is declared mode `in out`, but the input value is not referenced. This would be better as mode `out`.

Y is not needed. Ada has real arrays; they carry their bounds around with them as X'First, X'Last, and X'Length. Trying to index an array outside its bounds is an error (no buffer overflow vulnerabilities are possible). The usual way to iterate over an array is with the 'range attribute:

```
for I in X'range loop
```

This ensures that I is always a valid index into X.

Temp is not initialized, so it will normally be initialized to "stack junk". You should expect to get different results for different calls with the same inputs.

Instead of

```
     if count > Y then
        exit;
     end if;
```

it's more usual to write `exit when Count > Y;`

Since your procedure produces a single, scalar output, it would be more natural for it to be a function:

```
generic -- Sum
   type T is private;
   Zero : T;
   type T_List is array (Positive range <>) of T;
   with function "+" (Left : T; Right : T) return T is <>;
function Sum (X : T_List) return T;

function Sum (X : T_List) return T is
   Result : T := Zero;
begin -- Sum
   Add_All : for I in X'range loop
      Result := Result + X (I);
   end loop Add_All;

   return Result;
end Sum;
```

HTH